# Idle connection timeout limitation in IBM Cloud LBaaS causes problems in our applications

Tags: ibm-cloud, load-balancing

We are an IBM team using IBM Cloud LBaaS (load balancer service) for our applications running on IBM Cloud infrastructure. We got some customer complaints about being unable to get expected responses on the front end of our product, which they never met before with the previous deployment of our product on AWS. We investigated the issue and found that the connections of customers' requests got disconnected by the IBM Cloud load balancer because those requests took longer than 50 seconds to get a response from backend (those are some of our use cases with long running tasks).

We found the 50-second limitation of connection timeout here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/loadbalancer-service?topic=loadbalancer-service-advanced-traffic-management-with-ibm-cloud-load-balancer#connection-timeouts. **We are wondering if the idle timeout can be customized for us to cater for our long running tasks? If it's not supported for now, is there any plan to implement that in the future or is it possible to increase that limitation to a reasonable larger value?**

FYR, the max idle timeout of **AWS** load balancer service is **3600 seconds**: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/.

Any suggestions about how to resolve/eliminate this are appreciated. Feel free to email me directly (yang.zhang3@ibm.com) if you have anything to share. Thanks!

Yang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you referring to the idle connection timeout, it's mentioned in the same documentation link that you can set server and client timeout up to 7200 seconds (2 hours).

> Server-side & Client-side idle connection timeout value now can be
>   configured using API. User can configure server timeout(ParameterName:
>   serverTimeout) & client timeout(ParameterName: clientTimeout) value in
>   seconds upto 2 hours (Range: 1 to 7200 seconds) using
>   ‘UpdateLoadBalancerProtocols’ method of
>   ‘SoftLayer_Network_LBaaS_Listener’ service. If user does not provide
>   the server or client timeout value, load balancer will use default
>   value (mentioned in table) for the corresponding timeout.

For an example on how to use the `UpdateLoadBalancerProtocols` method, check this softlayer-python client example mentioned in the [API reference documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/loadbalancer-service?topic=loadbalancer-service-api-reference)

```
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint

# Your load balancer UUID
uuid = 'set me'

# New protocols to add
protocolConfigurations = [
    {
        "backendPort": 1350,
        "backendProtocol": "TCP",
        "frontendPort": 1450,
        "frontendProtocol": "TCP",
        "loadBalancingMethod": "WEIGHTED_RR",    # ROUNDROBIN, LEASTCONNECTION, WEIGHTED_RR
        "maxConn": 500,
        "sessionType": "SOURCE_IP"
    },
    {
        "backendPort": 1200,
        "backendProtocol": "HTTP",
        "frontendPort": 1150,
        "frontendProtocol": "HTTP",
        "loadBalancingMethod": "ROUNDROBIN",    # ROUNDROBIN, LEASTCONNECTION, WEIGHTED_RR
        "maxConn": 1000,
        "sessionType": "SOURCE_IP",
        "serverTimeout": 70,
        "clientTimeout": 70
    }
]

# Create the api client
client = SoftLayer.Client()
listener_service = client['Network_LBaaS_Listener']

_mask = "mask[listeners]"

try:
    response = listener_service.updateLoadBalancerProtocols(uuid, protocolConfigurations, mask=mask)
    pprint(response)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:            
    print("Unable to add protocols: %s, %s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Comment: Hi Vidyasagar, thanks for the update! We are so excited to know that it's configurable now. We will try that via the API and let you know the result later.

Comment: Hi Vidyasagar, yes, it worked for us, thanks for your help! Sorry, I posted my update in an Answer instead of a comment, and it was deleted (maybe by admin), sorry I was not familiar with the rules on StackOverflow. I'm pasting it here again:

Comment: This post is hidden. It was deleted 2 days ago by Bhargav Rao♦.

We were able to configure the timeouts of our load balancers via the API for Update a protocol https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/loadbalancer-service?topic=loadbalancer-service-api-reference#update-a-protocol. And we haven't seen the issue again after that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: # Your load balancer UUID
uuid = 'set me'

# New protocols to add
protocolConfigurations = [
    {   
        "listenerUuid": "set me",
        "serverTimeout": 3600,
        "clientTimeout": 3600
    },
    {   
        "listenerUuid": "set me",
        "serverTimeout": 3600,
        "clientTimeout": 3600
    }
]

# Create the api client
client = SoftLayer.Client()
listener_service = client['Network_LBaaS_Listener']

_mask = "mask[listeners]"

try:
    response = listener_service.updateLoadBalancerProtocols(uuid, protocolConfigurations, mask=_mask)

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I can't paste code snippets in comments. And I can't post it as an  answer. It's kind of unfortunate for an effective communication.

Comment: Yes, I've already marked this as answer, thanks again. For anyone who meets the same issue, please check the documentation and make sure you set "listenerUuid" in your API request if you want to update an existing listener instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I assume this does not work with ALB. I tried but it can't find load balancer even though I passed a valid ID (UUID?).